# Can you assist with a Google Sheet formula to produce Job Cost, with given Expenses, fee, and profit margin?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, algebra

OK so I have simplified this down to illustrate and ask for help with the crux of my issue.

I run a calculator which easily produces a Gross Profit and Profit Margin number, based on Job cost, admin fee, and expenses. Using simple formulas.  (Job cost, and Expenses being entered by the user.  Admin fee being a set 10% of Job cost.)

However, I am trying to create a seemingly similar but reversed calculator to help my team get to a target Job Cost when they know the Expenses & target Profit Margin in advance. Also adding the admin fee (being 10% of the job cost) as an additional expense.

The above has really got me stuck.

I have created an example sheet / test sheet where you can make any changes.

Link to example sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qXGJ8Uyft88SJEg6Z3NdAtlkI4NdNdndL_oRcraq0UM/edit?usp=sharing

2 pages total.  Both are simplified calculators.  One is the existing top down to profit margin calculator, the other is the reversed calculator I need help with.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer me on this!  Cheers

Comment: I believe we solved this with the understanding that .9xRevenue-Expenses=.25xRevenue

Comment: so therefore I will try to figure that into a formula